# Execute a command on the local machine from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, linux, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible to execute a command on the server the rails app is residing on?

If so, how do I do it?

Update:

I mean executing a command like "kill 1999", or "wget http://..." or "cat" etc., on Linux and similar commands on Windows.

Comment: Do you mean from within the Rails app? Maybe you could provide an example to clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to execute any OS/System command from within ruby and thus from rails as well.

For example a directory listing could be done using

```
system("ls")
```

For more ways to run shell commands in ruby check this [article](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that there are two ways to do that

1. `system("wget http://..")`, this will not return the response
2. Use backticks `'wget http://..'`  this will return the response as a return parameter

Refer the link for details

http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands#disqus_thread

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3

cd into the application and type.

```
 rails c
```

rails 2

cd into the application and type.

```
 script/console
```

Comment: Thanks 458221. However, I meant executing something like "ls", or "kill 9123", or "wget url". Updating the question :)

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Should give you an idea about the different way we can access remote server / data.

Have a look at the rails runner and console.